# Short code for Venues

Tags: plugins, shortcode, events, plugin-event-organiser

I am using the Event Organiser plug in and I am trying to setup the "venues."

In the post my client and I would like a little more information on the venue to appear,
I found the short code for the Google Map, but there is no other information.
When I click on the location nothing happens.
Is there a short code to post more information on the Venue?

Answer (score 3):

There aren't currently any shortcodes for venue information (address, postcode, other meta etc). However, you can **copy** the `single-event.php` template (find it in the `templates` directory of the plug-in) into your theme and edit it there to include venue information via provided template functions:

### Available functions

*When used **inside the loop**, you don't need to provide any parameters - it uses the veneu of the current event.*

- `eo_get_venue_address()` - returns an array of the form

  ```
  array(
      'address' => ,//Address of the venue as entered on the admin page
      'postcode' => ,//Venue postcode
      'country' => ,//Venue country
  )
  ```
- `eo_get_venue()` - returns the venue ID of the current event
- `eo_get_venue_description()` - returns the description of the venue (`eo_venue_description()` *prints* it)
- `eo_get_venue_name()` - returns the name of the venue
- `eo_get_venue_meta(eo_get_venue(),'key')` - Get meta for this venue with key 'key'.

This is an incomplete list ([see source](https://github.com/stephenh1988/Event-Organiser/blob/1.5.7/includes/event-organiser-venue-functions.php) for more). Outside the loop you will need to provide a venue ID (int) or slug (string). Documentation can be found [here](http://www.harriswebsolutions.co.uk/event-organiser/documentation/function-reference/).

### Example

For instance, you could have the following to immediately after `<?php the_content();?>` in the template file, to print some venue details:

```
<div class="venue-details" >
     <?php printf('<h2> %s </h2>', eo_get_venue_name() ); ?>

     <?php
       $address = array_filter(eo_get_venue_address());
       if ($address)
         printf('<p> %s </p>', implode(', ', $address)); 
      ?>

      <?php printf('<div class="venue-description"> %s </div>', eo_get_venue_description() ); ?>

</div>
```

You will probably need to add some styling to make it look nice, or just use the appropriate classes for your theme.

### Note

I plan on adding some more shortcodes, but if you, or anyone does so before me, feel free to contact me via the [plug-in's forums](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/) - you'll get plenty of credit :).

I've not tested the above - so there may be syntax errors. If you have any problems implementing it, it might be best to contact me [via the forums](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/).